# Can't read from binary file - read some lines in UTF-8, some in binary

Tags: java

I have this code:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;

public class Main  {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        zero("zero.out");
        System.out.println(zeroRead("zero.out"));
    }

    public static String zeroRead(String name)  {

        try (FileInputStream fos = new FileInputStream(name);
             BufferedInputStream bos = new BufferedInputStream(fos);
             DataInputStream dos = new DataInputStream(bos)) {

            StringBuffer inputLine = new StringBuffer();
            String tmp;
            String s = "";
            while ((tmp = dos.readLine()) != null) {
                inputLine.append(tmp);
                System.out.println(tmp);
            }
            dos.close();
            return s;
        }
        catch (IOException e)  {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }


    public static void zero(String name)  {
        File file = new File(name);
        String text = "König" + "\t";

        try (FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
             BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(fos);
             DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(bos)) {

             dos.write(text.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
             dos.writeInt(50);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

`zero()` method writes data into file: the string is written in UTF-8, while the number is written in binary. `zeroRead()` read the data from file.

The file looks like this after zero() is executed:

[image]

This is what `zeroRead()` returns:

[image]

How do I read the real data `König\t50` from the file?

Comment: Note that the method [`DataInputStream.readLine()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/io/DataInputStream.html#readLine()) is deprecated with comment: "This method does not properly convert bytes to characters"

Comment: @Jesper `System.out.println("König")` works fine though. So console can print it. The problem `König` isn't saved in the String variable in zeroRead(). How do I return the correct string from zeroRead()?

Answer (score 3):

`DataInputStream`'s readLine method has javadoc that is almost yelling that it doesn't want to be used. You should heed this javadoc: **That method is bad and you should not use it**. It doesn't do charset encoding.

Your file format is **impossible** as stated: You have no idea when to stop reading the string and start reading the binary numbers. However, the way you've described things, it sounds like the string is terminated by a newline, so, the `\n` character.

There is no easy 'just make this filter-reader and call `.nextLine` on it available, as they tend to buffer. You can try this:

```
InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(bos, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
```

However, basic `readers` do not have a readLine method, and if you wrap this in a `BufferedReader`, it may read past the end (the 'buffer' in that name is not just there for kicks). You'd have to handroll a method that fetches one character at a time, appending them to a stringbuilder, ending on a newline:

```
StringBuilder out = new StringBuilder();

for (int c = isr.read(); c != -1 && c != '\n'; c = isr.read())
  out.append((char) c);

String line = out.toString();
```

will get the job done and won't read 'past' the newline and gobble up your binary number.

Comment: Thank you. It works and I can get `König`. How do I get the number `50` though? After the `\n` is reached?

Comment: Or just write that code yourself. It's fairly simple - make a 4-byte array, call `readFully` with that array on the `bos`, then turn that into an int using one of the static methods int has.